# Opendaylight Yang parser example

Tags: opendaylight, yang

Is Opendaylight Yang parser actively supported and/or updated? There is no good working example of Yang parser using opendaylight APIs. The one mentioned here is not compiling -- [Where to find examples for parsing YANG files using opendaylight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039195/where-to-find-examples-for-parsing-yang-files-using-opendaylight)

The `YangInferencePipeline` definition (`org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.stmt.rfc6020.YangInferencePipeline;`) is not found or it is not resolving to a Jar. I tried to search it on Jar finder.

Can someone please help with a reference to a working example? Thanks.